# OS X terminal history missing commands

Tags: macos, unix, command-line, terminal

I know that I entered a command the other day, but now I can't find it using `history` or .bash_history. Any ideas why this happens? I suspect it has to do with using multiple tabs in my OS X terminal, and somehow the history doesn't carry over between tabs, but I don't know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of OS X El Capitan 10.11, by default Bash is configured to save separate command histories for each terminal, so they can be restored separately for Resume.

Each individual history is also appended to the global history in ~/.bash_history when the shell is exited. If you quit Terminal and then re-open it—with or without Resume enabled—you should find that commands from every terminal are in ~/.bash_history. If you have Resume enabled, each restored terminal will only contain its restored history, but when you create a new terminal it will start with the latest global history.

Because all the command histories are appended to the global ~/.bash_history file, you may wish to increase the number of commands stored by setting the `HISTFILESIZE` environment variable so the latest terminal histories don't push the other terminal histories out of the file too soon. The default value is 500. I have mine set to 10,000. I also set `HISTSIZE` to 10,000 so I can navigate through the entire history (otherwise, only the last 500 will be read from the history file).

The script that arranges for separate command histories is in `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` in OS X El Capitan 10.11 and later. It contains extensive comments describing how the mechanism works, and how to customize or disable it.

Comment: What does it mean: "If You have Resume enabled". Where I can enable Resume option for my terminal?

Answer (score 27):

I had this issue with my terminal.  It turns out it was saving to newly generated files in the `~/.bash_sessions` folder.  This is part of a new method of managing bash sessions introduced with El Capitan outlined in the `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` file.  This is confirmed by the outpit of `echo $HISTFILE`.  To disable this behaviour, simply run `touch ~/.bash_sessions_disable`.  Then quit the Terminal app and restart it.  It should now save the history properly, as can be confirmed again via `echo $HISTFILE`.  I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much. I had this problem in MacOs High Sierra.

Comment: This bug still persists in Mojave (on a brand new Mac mini). It didn't save any bash history at all until I disabled the sessions as described here.

Comment: This tip didn't work for me in Mojave. I have the ~/.bash_sessions_disable file, but it still seems to arbitrarily remember different histories in different windows.

Comment: To disable sessions in the latest versions of macOS, you [need to change a similar setting in `~/.zprofile`](https://superuser.com/a/1610999/14797).

Comment: @Senseful That's great for Catalina forwards, but Mojave doesn't use ZSH, it still uses BASH. Still no solution for how to do this in Mojave.

Answer (score 3):

this happens to me all the time.  I open multiple command windows, and history is saved in the order they're closed.  The commands you're looking for might have gotten overwritten by another command window.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: in csh (the shell I use; actually tcsh) there is an option to merge in command history when you exit the shell.  It works, but it's slow if you have 10,000 lines in your history like I have.  Googling, there seem to ways to make bash do this too, but I'm not as familiar with bash.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty certain this is a bug. I logged in on a guest account so the configuration files are pristine. In the home directory, I did:

`touch .bash_history` and then `tail -f .bash_history` to see when commands got saved.

Commands are supposed to save to the global `.bash_history` file when the terminal session is closed. I found that at least half of the time, the commands were not saved to the file after closing out the terminal. It seemed pretty random as to when it would happen and when it wouldn't. It also seemed to come in streaks where it would many times in a row and then get flaky again. It seemed to work every time if I quit the terminal session with `exit` instead of Command-W.

Comment: There's definitely something buggy here. I always use `exit` and noticed that nothing was being written to `.bash_history` at all. After finding this post, I tried using command-W to close a window. Suddenly everything works fine, no matter how I close the window.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, when I type `history` it only shows me the latest 16 commands. However, I can recall older commands via Ctrl+R, so I know that the command history is actually longer.

As of 2021, the command history is located in a file called `.zsh_history`:

- Open your command terminal.
- Navigate to your home directory: `cd ~`
- List all files: `list -al`
- You should find it there.

You can open it with vi: `vi .zsh_history`, and search for your command.

Comment: This is a frustrating mess... # tail -n 1000 ~/.zsh_history

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'alias history="history 1"' >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc && history
```

Comment: Please [edit] and explain how this answers the question and - because it's an 11 years old questions with 5 other answers - what it adds to the answers already given.